# Got error when access https URL using HttpClient

Tags: c#, android, httprequest, httpclient

i'm using Visual Studio to build Android application. I'm using REST API to communicate the app with the server, and later i got this error

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request

this is my codes

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(defaultData.headerName, defaultData.headerData);
var json = await client.GetStringAsync("https://example.com/api");
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ArdilesmetroClass>(json);
```

This problem occurs when i try to accessing https url and it works fine when accessing http. What i need to add in my codes?

Answer (score 0):

Done, i have the answer.Go to your Project Properties->Android Options-> Click Advanced. You need to change SSL/TLS implementation to

> Native TLS 1.2+

[image: Android Option]